# How can one get an analytic continuation of a power series?

Tags: power-series, analytic-continuation

What method should one use to get an analytic continuation of this power series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n\#}$$
; where $n\#$ is the product of all primes less or equal to $n$.

The radius of convergence for this series equals $e$.

Comment: The explicit formula for $\log n\#$ doesn't converge absolutely so it is unlikely we can write your series as $\sum_j c_j Li_{z_j}(x)$, ie. analytic continuation is unlikely. If you replace $1/ n\#$ by $\exp(\sum_{p^k\le x} \log p (1-p^k/x))$ it may work better.

Comment: @reuns Can you help me out with this?

Comment: For those interested in doing the computations, see some ideas in the comments to [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3572546/752802).