# On analytic continuation

Tags: power-series, analytic-continuation

If we have a power series, can we always get an analytic continuation of it? And if not, when can we? And is there a simple general method to get an analytic continuation of a divergent  power series?

Comment: The question is in general delicate. See for instance [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46898/power-series-without-analytic-continuation?rq=1) for examples of series which cannot be extended outside the disk. It is also not hard to construct power series which have radius of convergence zero.

Comment: @Joshua Mundinger Considering series which can be extended outside the disk, what are the most efficient methods to do this (to extend the series)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3565853/how-can-one-get-an-analytic-continuation-of-a-power-series     Can this series be extended?

Comment: If you have a power series centered at the origin $\sum_n a_nz^n$ and radius of convergence $r$, you can check if it has a continuation in the direction of $0<|a|<r$ by expanding $\sum_{n}a_n[(z-a)+a]^n$ in powers of $z-a$ and computing its radius of convergence. There will be an extension to the point $r\frac{a}{|a|}$ if and only if the radius of that series is larger than $r-|a|$.

Comment: @flan Is that possible for this series? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3565853/how-can-one-get-an-analytic-continuation-of-a-power-series

Comment: I don't know. I would use some bounds, $4^{-n}$ and $2^{-n}$, on the coefficients to see what those imply. If $a_n$ is your $\frac{1}{n\#}$, then the coefficient of the expansion around $a$ will have coefficients $b_n=a_n+\binom{n+1}{1}a_{n+1}a+\binom{n+1}{2}a_{n+2}a^2+...$. See what the known bounds on $a_n$ tell you about the behaviour of $b_n^{1/n}$. A value of $a$ (a direction) that you don't need to test is $a$ being positive real. Phringsheim's theorem, proven exactly using this technique shows that because $a_n$ are all non-negative, then $e$ is a singular point of your function.

Comment: Oop! The expression that I wrote above for the coefficients $b_n$ should have been $b_n=a_n+\frac{n+1}{1}a_{n+1}a+\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2!}a_{n+2}a^2+\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{3!}a_{n+3}a^2+...$.

Comment: @flan Thank you! $a$ can be any positive real number?

Comment: No, $a$ should be a complex number, different from $0$ and with absolute value less than $e$, which is the radius of convergence of your series. In a comment above I mentioned that for your series, since all coefficients are real and non-negative, Phringsheim's theorem says that $z=e$ is a singular point of your series. So, it is not going to be useful taking $a$ positive (real). Since there is not going to be analytic continuation in that direction. The first point that I would try is $a=-1/2$. It is possible that your series does have a continuation to $z=-e$.

Comment: @flan Is it possible that it has a continuation to all real numbers except $e$?

Comment: Maybe. For example, the series $1+z/2+z^2/2^2+z^3/2^3+...=\frac{2}{2-z}$ and $1+z/4+z^2/4^2+z^3/4^3+...=\frac{4}{4-z}$ both have an analytic continuation beyond their disc of convergence, in all directions, except for one: In the direction of the positive real ray. The first one has a singular point at $z=2$ and the second at $z=4$. That is why I suggested looking at the direction of the negative real ray.

Comment: @flan Thank you! I would appreciate it if you helped me out with solving this problem!

Comment: I calculated the first 10 coefficients, with $a=\frac{1}{2}$:

b(0)= -0.3859608597248

b(1)= -0.4538668705970


b(2)= -0.0119798816676

b(3)= -0.3293664416242

b(4)= 0.03824109001952

b(5)= -0.1078221222899

b(6)= 0.02904264682306

b(7)= -0.0493044952764

b(8)= 0.03681984080868

b(9)= -0.0307270838564

b(10)= 0.0067319124017